# Spring boot google app engine stopped working with error: com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntimeMainWithDefaults

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I haven't changed anything on our deployment process and it just started failing with the following error: com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntimeMainWithDefaults

```
I0110 00:43:48.066641    20 jvmti_agent.cc:159] Java debuglet initialization started
I0110 00:43:48.067340    20 jvmti_agent.cc:193] Java debuglet initialization completed
I0110 00:43:48.161763    20 jvmti_agent.cc:204] Java VM started
I0110 00:43:48.178575    20 jvmti_agent.cc:214] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMInit initialization time: 16827 microseconds
I0110 00:43:48.178737    34 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:95] Agent thread started: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
I0110 00:43:48.185597    34 jvm_internals.cc:370] Loading internals from /opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent_internals.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntimeMainWithDefaults
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntimeMainWithDefaults
I0110 00:43:48.235134    20 jvmti_agent.cc:222] Java VM termination
I0110 00:43:48.346659    34 jvmti_agent.cc:365] Initializing Cloud Debugger Java agent version: 2.29
I0110 00:43:48.348253    34 jni_logger.cc:31] Initializing ClassPathLookup, default classpath: true, extra classpath: [/workspace/WEB-INF/classes, /workspace/WEB-INF/lib]
W0110 00:43:48.479976    34 jni_logger.cc:46] Failed to index JAR file /base/java11_runtime/runtime-main.jar
```

Comment: Based from the logs you provided, the issue might be related to your classpath entries. Can you provide further details like your classpath file?

Comment: Same problem here, then I tried to update versions of app engine on pom.xml, and make a new deployment, but errors persists, anyone from @GoogleCloud can hurry up this bug for us?

Comment: the mentioned issue doesn't work for me. here is another issue with the same topic: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213864291 looks like they rolled back the problematic update.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusZancolò! the temporary workaround mentioned in that issue works for me. Keeping an eye for when we need to revert it